# What is the time complexity for string equality query in databases like sql or oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Let's say I have a database with string entries in it, and I need to look for a certain string, say "gamma". What would be the time complexity if I search for the particular string via this query :

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE NAME='GAMMA'
```

Is there a faster or more efficient way to do this? Would it be better if I stored SHA256 of the strings as this would ensure a fixed size even if the string is large (assuming that string comparison happens according to O(length of string)?

Assume that only unique entries of strings are there.

Comment: if you have index on `name`, i think is `O(log(n))` n number of strings

Comment: What exactly do you mean by having index on name? Does it mean having unique id?

Comment: Nope, just create the index for the field `CREATE INDEX index_name
ON table_name (column1);` You can add the keyword `UNIQUE` if is a key field

Comment: To learn more about indexes see https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/CNCPT/indexiot.htm

Comment: Double quotes are for delimited identifiers. Use single quotes for string literals.

Comment: I'd also recommend to read about query optimizazion in oracle, partitioning and indexing in general if you are interested in a fast usable db

Comment: as a follow up, would the analyze statement in sql help in finding which columns to index?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty meaningless question in SQL.  This query can be approached in multiple different ways:

- Doing a full table scan
- Using an index on `(name)` or name is the first column of any index, followed by a row lookup
- Doing a partial table scan, if `name` is a partitioning column
- Doing a binary search, if the table is an index-organized table

And there are variations and complexities on these.

When thinking about the performance of SQL queries, you generally want to think about the I/O operations needed for the set, so about the complexity of specific operations.  That said, some operations are quite expensive, so sometimes you need to take that into account.  String comparison on relatively short strings is not one of those operations.

If you have large strings, then hashing the string can be a helpful optimization -- particularly for comparing strings in different rows.  However, it comes at the cost of query complexity.  An index is typically sufficient for this operation.

Comment: Okay, so if I hash the strings that I intend to store and I index the hashes, would that be a good idea (as that would ensure constant length, or would indexing take care of that for me)? Also, how would hashing cost query complexity?

Comment: @SarveshKesharwani . . . Hashing will help, but you still need to compare the strings when the hashes match, because hashing is not 100% sure.  If you are willing to settle for a very rare incorrect equality, then it is a viable solution.  You just have to remember to hash all inputs (and references in other tables).